# How to read backup name of a database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When running the `BACKUP` command, like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE dbname TO DISK ... etc.
```

You can specify a name for the backup with this option:

```
NAME = N'something'
```

I have many backup files and need to read the `NAME` property if there was specified one. How do I do it?

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to get the file names of the backup files from the file system by using pure t-sql, right?

Comment: No, not the file names. The field NAME that can be specified with the command BACKUP DATABASE in MSSQL. [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: This is even less clear now. What exactly is your situation? do you get an sql statement as a variable and need to parse it? do you need a way to look at sql statements that was executed?  Is it something else I didn't think about?

Comment: On the page I linked it says: "Optionally, specify one or more WITH options. 

 NAME = { backup_set_name | @backup_set_name_var }

    Specifies the name of the backup set. Names can have a maximum of 128 characters. If NAME is not specified, it is blank."

Comment: I'm assuming that this optional NAME is stored in the .bak file somewhere. How do I read it?

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand your question now.
You can get all the data (including the `name`) of the backups made in the server by querying the [`backupset`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299(v=sql.105).aspx) table in `msdb` database.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
```

**Note**: This table contains only data of successful backup operations:

> Contains a row for each backup set. A backup set contains the backup from a single, successful backup operation.

Comment: Thank you. That shows a list of all backups performed just as you said. I can compare teh time with the file's timestamp. But is there a way to read that information without having the SQL server available? Is the NAME field not stored into the .bak file too?

Comment: I have no idea. I've never tried to look inside an sql server .bak file. I don't even know if it's textual or binary, but according to [this article](http://sqlbak.com/blog/open-a-bak-file/), the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the name of backup files use something like this:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\BackupfilePath\BackUpfileName.bak'
GO
```

This code will give you information of your backup-file.

> Note: `Name` will comes as `BackUpName` field.

You can do this also with [Power Shell](http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/get-database-backup-details-powershell).